# pysftp.Connection.walktree() fails if any directory don't have read permission

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am using pysftp connection using `walktree()` method to list all files as below

```
with pysftp.Connection(domain, username=USER,
                       password=PWD, port=port,
                       cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:

    # call back method to list the files for the directory found in walktree
    def dir_found_list_files(path):
        if path:
            files = sftp.listdir_attr(path)
            for file in files:
                if 'r' in file.longname[:4]:
                    filelist.append(path+'/'+file.filename)

    # call back method when file found in walktree
    def file_found(path):
        pass

    # call back method when unknown found in walktree
    def unknown_file(path):
        pass

    # sftp walk tree to list files
    sftp.walktree("/", file_found, dir_found_list_files, unknown_file, recurse=True)
```

This part works fine. But when any of the folder does not have the permission to read, the `walktree` method raises the permission exception.
How can I ignore the the access denied folder and continue with `walktree` for accessible folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The `Connection.walktree` does not allow such customization.

But the method is quite trivial, check [its source code](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/master/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-883). Just copy the code over and customize it anyway you need. Something like this (untested):

```
def robust_walktree(sftp, remotepath, fcallback, dcallback, ucallback, recurse=True)
    try:
        entries = sftp.listdir(remotepath)
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EACCES:
            raise
        else
            entries = []

    for entry in entries:
        pathname = posixpath.join(remotepath, entry)
        mode = sftp.stat(pathname).st_mode
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            # It's a directory, call the dcallback function
            dcallback(pathname)
            if recurse:
                # now, recurse into it
                robust_walktree(sftp, pathname, fcallback, dcallback, ucallback)
        elif S_ISREG(mode):
            # It's a file, call the fcallback function
            fcallback(pathname)
        else:
            # Unknown file type
            ucallback(pathname)
```

Comment: This works fine with small modifications: Thank you.